# error 1324:undefined cursor in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**my code is**: below is my cursor declaration but it shows **error 1324:undefined cursor** why?please help me

```
 Set v_sqlCmd1 = CONCAT('DECLARE endtCursor Cursor for Select endorsementId from TxnEndorsement where txnRecNo=' + Cast(p_txnRecNo As char (20)));
        SET @stmt_str =  v_sqlCmd1;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_str;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        OPEN endtCursor;//shows  error 1324:undefined endtCursor
```

is there any mistake to declere a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you are trying to write a stored procedure in MYSQL
And the problem is not with Cursor.

As you have not pasted the whole stored procedure,

standard stored procedure goes like this

```
drop procedure if exists procname;
delimiter $$

create procedure procname
(
in arg int default 0
)
begin    
## Do the operations you want here your cursor and whatever    
end$$

delimiter ;
```

I will suggest pasting whole Stored procedure! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have not fully asked a question here but the syntax of a cursor should look similar to this:

```
Declare <cursor_name> CURSOR
STATIC/FORWARD_ONLY/DYNAMIC/KEYSET/SCROLL/READ_ONLY
FOR 
<Any Select Query>
..
..
GO
..
OPEN <Cursor_Name>
FETCH NEXT/FIRST/PRIOR
FROM <Cursor_Name>
..
..
CLOSE <Cursor_Name>
DEALLOCATE <Cursor_Name>
```